# Gulp + wiredep + browsersync + bower = components not found

Tags: npm, browser-sync, gulp-watch

I have a build / dist folder structure, with bower_componentes folder at the root of my app folder.

Is there a way to configure browserSync so my web browsers load the css and js resources from Bower correctly?

If I use browserSync's baseDir parameter set to './dist' the deploy folder works but the dependencies don't.

If I use browserSync's baseDir parameter set to './' the dependencies work, but I have to manually type '/dist' at the browser's address bar.

Or is this how it's supposed to work?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access a directory outside of the *baseDir* you will need to use a route in your browsersync int.

https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-server

```
// Since version 1.2.1
// The key is the url to match
// The value is which folder to serve (relative to your current working directory)

server: {
    baseDir: "./dist",
    routes: {
        "/bower_components": "bower_components"
    }
}
```